# How to get the docker host name in azure itoedge enviroment variable

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Hi I am trying to get the hostname into my azure module by getting it form the enviroment variables. the module is written in C# and .NetCore 3.1

```
var deviceId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOST_HOSTNAME");
```

I have tried to add the variable in de deployment template

```
    "createOptions": {
               "Cmd": [
                    "-e HOST_HOSTNAME=(hostname)"
                  ]
       }
```

The result is

```
    deviceId == null
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `"env"` in your deployment template? You should add it on the same level as "settings" JSON object. Something like:

```
"env": {
        "HOS_HOSTNAME": {
            "value": "<valuehere>"
        }
    }
```

You can also do this in the Azure Portal. See for example how is done in the tutorial [Give modules access to a device's local storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-access-host-storage-from-module?view=iotedge-2020-11)

[image]